# React shortcut to importing style files

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm working in a React project.
In a component's specific SASS file, I import SASS partials like this:

```
@import '../../styles/fonts';
```

When I was working in Angular project, the previous path could be simplified with:

```
@import 'fonts';
```

And how this can be achieved is by adding a configuration to ".angular.cli.json" as described in this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components.

My Question is: is there a way to achieve the same result in a React project? and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Webpack aliases ( assuming that you're using webpack ) to resolve the imports and then use the alias name in your scss file to import the module like this :

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
 resolve: {
    alias: {
       styles: path.join(__dirname, 'app/styles') 
   }
 }
};
```

and import like

```
@import '~styles/variables';
```

For more info refer these

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/
- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#resolving-import-at-rules

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It not only helped me for this specific problem, but form other import problems  as well.